# PHP - set default timezone offset for areas without timezone name (sea locations)

Tags: php, datetime, timezone, timezone-offset

I am writing PHP app that uses timezones. For land based GPS, I use

```
date_default_timezone_set();
```

with correct name like `Europe/Dublin`. However, if the GPS location is not land but it is on the sea, there is no timezone name, but time is offseted from UTC. The calculation is aprox. 1 hour for 15 degrees of longitude. I have calculated UTC offset manually, but I am not able to set it to PHP. I am using `date` method to print human-readable dates from unix timestamps.

I have found that there are Others timezones names (https://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.others.php) like `Etc/GMT+10`, but the PHP documentation states this:

> **Warning** Please do not use any of the timezones listed here (besides UTC), they
>   only exist for backward compatible reasons, and may expose erroneous
>   behavior.

Is it safe to use the `Etc`-based offsets? Or is there any other safe solution? I have not found any. In `date_default_timezone_set()` comments  someone "uses" this: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php#96551 but it seems very ugly.

I am using PHP 7.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The time zones in PHP originate from the [IANA tz database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database).

In particular, zones like `Etc/GMT+10` originate from the `etcetera` file in the tz data, [which says](https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/master/etcetera#L6-L11) (emphasis mine):

> ... These days, the
>   tz files cover almost all the inhabited world, and ***the only practical
>   need now for the entries that are not on UTC are for ships at sea***
>   that cannot use POSIX TZ settings.

Thus, you can indeed and should use them for the purpose you described.

Keep in mind that they only exist for whole-hour offsets from `Etc/GMT-14` to `Etc/GMT+12`, and that the sign in the zone name is opposite from standard conventions.  In other words `Etc/GMT+10` is actually UTC-10.

One other note.  My understanding is that it is common for ships at sea to use a land-based time zone when they are in the territorial waters near such lands, including any daylight saving time adjustment in effect.  For example, a ship traveling within the territorial waters of the USA along the Pacific coast should change their clocks to use PST (UTC-8) in the winter and PDT (UTC-7) in the summer.  This is modeled by `America/Los_Angeles`, whereas a pure longitudinal calculation would use UTC-8 year-round (`Etc/GMT+8`).

All of this is flexible, as the captain of the ship can basically decide the shipboard time at their discretion.  See Wikipedia's article on [nautical time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nautical_time#Modern_application) for more specifics.

You might also want to [read here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16086964/634824) about methods to use GPS coordinates to resolve an IANA time zone.  Those that use the [Time Zone Boundary Builder](https://github.com/evansiroky/timezone-boundary-builder) project as a data source (such as [the Geo-Timezone PHP library](https://github.com/minube/geo-timezone)) benefit from both nautical time and territorial waters being taken into consideration.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer.